# Scroll Left and Right a div with floating elements

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div with a fixed width and with many images insides which are aligned horizontally by `float:left;`, so the div is scrolling horizontally using the scrollBar. I want to scroll elements (like slider) by clicking on two "**NEXT**" and "**PREVIOUS**" images.

I have did something like  :

```
$("a.previous-menu").click(function(){
    $(".menu-items").animate({
        left: "+=50"}, 5000, function() {
    });
});
```

But it appears that this solution works only when the elements are aligne by `position: absolute;` or `position: relative` and it doesn't work with floating elements.

Do you have any idea about this ?

Comment: only `absolute/relative` elems are used to do some animation.

Comment: Check this http://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/kuAzl

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".menu-items").animate({scrollLeft: 50}, 800);
```

This will scroll 50 px left over five seconds.

Comment: This is used only with `absolute / relative` positions.

Comment: You need to scroll the container not its items